# How to get boundary of Java's SOAPMessage?

Tags: java, soap

I am creating a SOAPMessage in Java and sending it as a response to the client by writing the SOAPMessage to HttpServletResponse's outPutStream. The SOAPMessage has an attachment. I can set the response's Content-Type to multipart/related but I want to also add the boundary name. When I send the response, the boundary is somehow automatically generated by Java (I don't add it myself). How can I get the generated boundary or how can I set the name myself?

Example of the generated part

```
------=_Part_0_878533912.1592388475903
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
MimeHeaders mimeHeaders = reply.getMimeHeaders();
String header = mimeHeaders.getHeader("Content-Type")[0];
response.setHeader("Content-Type", header);
```

where response is an instance of HttpServletResponse and reply is an instance of SOAPMessage.